# Placing all tables into one database - Good or Bad

Tags: sql, database, database-design

**Two scenarios:**

*Large application - One database w/all tables*

or

*Large application - Multiple databases w/relevant tables*

Can anyone list the advantages/disadvantages?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Your question does not fit well with the kind of questions preferred on this site, it may be closed as 'Non-constructive', it's too subjective. Look around at the other questions and see what kind of question is preferred.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Unless you have very specific reasons, keep everything in one single database. I cannot think of a single advantage of splinting one single schema into multiple DBs.

One single database creates one single unit of recovery, which allows for a consistent backup. It also presents one single unit of failover for high availability. With multiple databases one cannot take a consistent backup unless it freezes activity (often impossible). also multiple databases pose challenges in orchestrating a 'group' failover in case of failure (some DBs may failover to a new server, while other may stay behind).

Multiple databases offer advantages in multi-tenant models where each tenant can have its own database, specially if tenants may choose or opt-in on version upgrades (this is impossible with single DB). But this is a scenario with many databases having the same schema (same tables in every database), not splitting a schema across several DBs.

Scale out by data partitioning (sharding) can only be achieved by having multiple databases, but that is a different topic from splitting a database into 'parts' (each DB with a different schema). Shards have identical schema, but contain data for specific ranges.

Comment: Thank you, so much. Exactly the answer I was looking for.